# How to replace tokens if they are used together?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, token, sentiment-analysis

I would like to do a sentimental analysis on the topic COVID-19 using python. The problem arises that entries like "positive tested" receive a positive polarity, although this statement is a negative declaration. My current code is as follows:

```
import nltk
from textblob import TextBlob
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

# Setting the test string
test_string = "He was tested positive on Covid-19"

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(test_string)

# Lemmatizer
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

tokens_lem_list = []
for word in tokens:
    lem_tokens = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos="v")
    tokens_lem_list.append(lem_tokens)

# List to string
tokens_lem_str = ' '.join(tokens_lem_list)

# Print the polarity of the string
print(TextBlob(tokens_lem_str).sentiment.polarity)
```

With the following output:

```
0.22727272727272727

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Therefore, I want to delete the tokens "test" and "positive", if they are used together, and replace them with the word "ill". Should I use a loop or would this only eat up my computing capacity with a large amount of text?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is your exact question? About the code to change `positive test` or `test positive` to `disease`, or about time complexity problem?

Comment: Rather the first one. But I have solved it. Thanks for your message. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem as follows:

```
# Producing a loop which finds "positive" and "negative" tested string entries
matches_positive = ["test", "positive"]
matches_negative = ["test", "negative"]

replaced_testing_term_sentence = []
for sentence_lem in sentences_list_lem:
    # Constrain to replace "positive tested" by "not healthy"
    if all(x in sentence_lem for x in matches_positive):
        sentence_lem = [word.replace("positive", "not healthy") for word in sentence_lem]
        sentence_lem.remove("test")
        replaced_testing_term_sentence.append(sentence_lem)
    # Constrain to replace "negative tested" by "not ill"
    elif all(x in sentence_lem for x in matches_negative):
        sentence_lem = [word.replace("negative", "not ill") for word in sentence_lem]
        sentence_lem.remove("test")
        replaced_testing_term_sentence.append(sentence_lem)
    # Constrain to remain not matching sentences in the data sample
    else:
        replaced_testing_term_sentence.append(sentence_lem)
```

It does the job. The selected replacement terms are deliberately chosen. If anybody sees potential for optimization, I would appreciate a comment.